# CSS3 shorthand for transition div 100px from the bottom to the final state

Tags: css, position, css-transitions, css-animations

Trying to do a transition effect where when the user first enters the page, the div 'caption' starts out 100px below it's final resting position and animates upwards. This is the code I'm using in my CSS, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.caption { padding: 0 0 0 0; transition: padding 0.25s ease-in-out 1.0s 0 0 100px 0; }
```

I believe you can animate padding as well as top. Tried both approaches but neither worked. What would here?

Comment: Can you post your code on codepen.io so we can see it in context?

Comment: You **cannot** append the final state values to the `transition` property. That is not how transition works. I don't mean to be rude but you need to have a look at the basics (again).

Comment: I did, Harry. But it didn't make sense to me. That's why I'm asking here. CSS3 Transition can be very confusing. It's not like you just got a UI like in the old Flash days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final state values cannot be appended to the `transition` property's value like in the code below. The property's values can only be details about which property should be transitioned, the duration of the transition, the delay and timing function etc.

```css
transition: padding 0.25s ease-in-out 1.0s 0 0 100px 0;
                                           ^  
                                           |_ Everything from here on in are incorrect
```

Another thing to note is, `transition` is not the right choice for this us-case. Transitions happen only when the properties on an element change due to some  action (like `:hover`, `:focus`, addition of new class on click using JS etc). There is no pure CSS way to trigger `transition` on page load. You can use scripting and auto trigger state changes based on time-out but I feel that is unnecessarily complex for something that can be achieved using CSS in a different way.

You have added a delay to the transition but this does not represent the time after which the transition should start automatically. It represents the time that should elapse after the state changes are applied before which the transition can commence.

---

Animations should be used for automatically triggering changes on page load. Unlike transition, they are auto invoked. You can read more about CSS animations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

For animating an element from 100px below its final resting position to the top, any one of the following properties could be used:

- `margin-top`
- `top` (can be used for elements with `absolute` positioning)
- `translateY()`

**Using margin-top:**

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;  /* starting position */
  animation: move-up 1s linear forwards;
            /* values are [animation-name] [animation-duration] [animation-timing-function] [animation-fill-mode] */
}
@keyframes move-up {
  to {
    margin-top: 0px;  /* final resting position */
  }
}

/* Just for demo */

.caption {
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<!-- library is only to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class='caption'>This is a caption</div>
```

**Using top:**

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 100px; /* starting position */
  animation: move-up 1s linear forwards;
             /* values are [animation-name] [animation-duration] [animation-timing-function] [animation-fill-mode] */
}
@keyframes move-up {
  to {
    top: 0px; /* final resting position */
  }
}

/* Just for demo */

.caption {
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<!-- library is only to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='caption'>This is a caption</div>
```

**Using translateY():**

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(100px); /* starting position */
  animation: move-up 1s linear forwards;
             /* values are [animation-name] [animation-duration] [animation-timing-function] [animation-fill-mode] */
}
@keyframes move-up {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px); /* final resting position */
  }
}

/* Just for demo */

.caption {
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<!-- library is only to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='caption'>This is a caption</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that education. Really helped out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "." because you said you are use **caption** div not class.
And it is not possible to detect a user or page has been load in css so you have to use jQuery or something else.
**this is CSS**

```
    caption
            {
                transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
                -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
                -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;}
```

I'm using jQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("caption").css("padding-bottom", "100px");
});
</script>
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: (1) It is possible to do what the OP wants with pure CSS. (2) You should avoid posting JS/jQuery answers unless OP indicates that they are fine with it (or tagged it). While I don't downvote for that reason, there is a high probability that somebody else will. (3) Even if we have to take the route of scripting, jQuery is **absolutely not required** for such a small thing.

Comment: The style is a class called 'caption. So I did do it right. I am not using the caption tag at all.

Comment: but you said div "caption" that;s why i thought caption is div

Comment: and harry please show me how to run any animation when user come on page or page will completely loaded in pure CSS...
Please if its possible, than i also want to learn.

Comment: @RajnishRajput: Have a look at my answer for ways to do it. Side note - Use @ before username while responding in comments because without it notifications are not triggered.

Comment: @Harry but your are not detecting that and play animation when user come on the page or page fully loaded you just play the animation in under 1s.

Comment: And where exactly is your answer checking if the *user come on the page*? Your code is executed on page load and that is the same thing that the animation used in my answer does too. And the page is loaded only when the user enters the page.

Comment: no my code run when document is ready its mean when page completely loaded